# How can I monitor when original version of shadow copied assembly changes in app domain

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I'm creating a service that hosts and runs other smaller services in separate app domains (Sort of like a mini IIS).  When each service gets registered on startup, I run the following code:

```
AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup
{
    LoaderOptimization = LoaderOptimization.MultiDomain,
    ShadowCopyDirectories = service.FullPath, // Directory service binary lives in
    ShadowCopyFiles = Convert.ToString(true)
};

AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(service.Name, null, setup);
ServiceDomain s = domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap<ServiceDomain>();
s.RegisterService(service, DefaultPort);
```

This basically sets up an app domain, enables shadow copy, and calls `RegisterService` in the new app domain.  The `RegisterService` method will create an instance of an object, which will load the shadow copied assembly into memory.

For example, a service might contain the type `ServiceFoo` in the assembly `Foo.dll`.  `Foo.dll` lives in `service.FullPath`, and thus gets shadow copied over when the app domain is loaded.  From this point on, I can *delete or modify* the original `Foo.dll` in the `service.FullPath` directory, which is great.

However, when someone *modifies* the original `Foo.dll` (For example, they copy in a new version over the network), I want to be notified so I can unload the old app domain and create it again with the new version of the assembly.

Basically, what I'm trying to do here is provide the ability for administrators to deploy new versions of services without disrupting other services running in the same process.

**My Question:** How can I be notified when `Foo.dll` is modified, or perhaps any file in the `ShadowCopyDirectories` directory changes?  I'm sure I could check time stamps in these directories every few seconds, but it seems like there should be a better way.  What's the best approach for this situation?

**Update:**

My current ideas all resolve around `FileWatcher`.  However, figuring out which file(s) to watch is proving to my difficult.

**Idea 1:** Monitor `service.FullPath`, which is the directory that contains the file that might be changed.  However, multiple services might live in this directory.  If I monitor the directory, a change to one file might cause false restarts on services that don't actually use that file.

**Idea 2:** Parse `service.TypeName`, which is a string containing the fully qualified type name.  .NET provides ways to parse these strings, such as `Type.GetType(string)`, which would then allow me to get access to the code base.  However, the second I load the assembly into the parent app domain, it becomes locked so I can't change it anymore.  I could attempt to parse `TypeName` by hand, but this syntax is rather complex.  There are whole libraries that attempt to parse this syntax.

**Idea 3:** Monitor the `AssemblyLoad` event:

```
domain.AssemblyLoad += (sender, args) =>
{
    string test = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
    Uri fileUri = new Uri(args.LoadedAssembly.CodeBase);
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileUri.LocalPath);
};
```

This gets fired when the domain loads an assembly.  I can detect if `fileInfo.Directory` is the same as `service.FullPath` and set up a watch on that file if so.  One problem.  This delegate gets run within the context of `domain`.  I don't have any access to the `ServiceResolver` or anything within the root domain.

**Idea 4:** After I call `s.RegisterService`, check `domain.GetAssemblies()` and try to find ones that came from `service.FullPath`.  However, when I run:

```
var assemblies = domain.GetAssemblies();
```

It immediately throws the exception:

> Type 'System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder' in assembly
>   'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.

I'm not quite sure why this is.  I'm guessing `GetAssemblies()` is only meant to be called on the current AppDomain.

Comment: can you not create a FileWatcher and have it point to the .Dll based on the changes like CreateTime etc...??

Comment: Yea that might be the best solution.  Though it's proving to be a bit hacky to figure out what file to monitor just based on the type name.  The second I try to resolve the type, it's loaded into the app domain and locked forever.  There's no way to *parse* type names without loading them.  Now I have some ideas around the `AssemblyLoad` event on the `AppDomain`, I think I'm getting somewhere with that.

Comment: Actually that doesn't work because the `AssemblyLoad` event gets run in the context of the new app domain, so I don't have access to anything within the host.

Comment: have you looked a the following just wondering http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25y1ya39(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried this particular google search maybe it will lead to some better ideas [c# accessing AssemblyLoad in Domain host Application](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+accessing+AssemblyLoad+in+Domain+host+Application&oq=c%23+accessing+AssemblyLoad+in+Domain+host+Application&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.523j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @DJKRAZE - Just updated my question.  Basically, if I load the type into the current domain, that assembly is locked and I can no longer update it. (See Idea 2)

Comment: doing a quick google search on your exact error message looks like you may need to call `method: Appdomain.UnLoad().`

Comment: @DJKRAZE - Thanks for your ideas!  I got a basic prototype working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I did.  First, I created a new class called `ServiceDomainProxy` which looks like so:

```
internal class ServiceDomainProxy : MarshalByRefObject
{
    private ServiceController controller;
    private List<FileSystemWatcher> watchers;

    public ServiceDomainProxy(ServiceController controller)
    {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    public void CreateMonitor(Uri fileUri)
    {
        if(watchers == null)
            watchers = new List<FileSystemWatcher>();

        // Setup a FileWatcher on type, notify controller whenever it reloads
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileUri.LocalPath);
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
        {
            Path = file.DirectoryName,
            Filter = file.Name
        };

        watcher.Changed += fileChanged;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        watchers.Add(watcher);
    }

    void fileChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Controller.Log.Info("Reloading Service Assembly: {0}", e.Name);
        // TODO: Call the Reload method on controller
    }
}
```

This class basically acts as a proxy between domains.  Next, I've modified my `ServiceDomain` class to have a constructor that takes a `ServiceDomainProxy` instance:

```
public ServiceDomain(ServiceDomainProxy proxy)
{
    this.proxy = proxy;
}
```

I have to update my `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` call to pass in an instance of `ServiceDomainProxy` as well:

```
Type t = typeof(ServiceDomain);
ServiceDomain s = domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(t.Assembly.FullName, t.FullName, false, BindingFlags.Default, null, new object[] { proxy }, null, null);
```

Then, in `ServiceDomain.RegisterService`, I can *register* the resolved type with the `ServiceDomainProxy`:

```
proxy.CreateMonitor(new Uri(service.ResolveType().Assembly.CodeBase));
```

This calls the original instance of `ServiceDomainProxy`, across app domain bounders, which can then set up the file system monitor and alert the controller that the service needs to be reloaded.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: You could just use `AppDomain.DoCallBack` and marshall `GetAssemblies()` manually.